# How to disable multi level bootstrap dropdown?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I want user to be able to select everything within Morphological Transformation (Erosion, Dilation, Opening, Closing), but not 'Morphological Transformation' itself. Thank you for every answer!

[image]

HTML Code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <hr>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <a id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#" href="/page.html">
            Select Pre-Processing Method <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
          <li><a href="#">Normalisation</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Canny Edge Detection</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Smoothing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"></a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>

 ... 
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Morphological Transformation</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a>Erosion</a></li>
              <li><a>Dilation</a></li>
              <li><a>Opening</a></li>
              <li><a>Closing</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

  ...


            </ul>
          </li> 
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you considered adding `.disabled` to the `li`element? http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns-disabled

Comment: I have tried that, but it did not work because I users need to be able to click on it to show the sub-menu. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **disable** anchor events and **keep hover** effects by using this:

```css
.disabled-link:hover{
   background: red;
}

.disabled-link:active{
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="www.google.com" class="disabled-link">Test</a>
```

It is **usable** for all modern browsers:
[click!](http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events)